# is there a way to use sagemath in chaquopy

Tags: android, sage, chaquopy

i want to make a mobile app, preferably in Android Studio with Kotlin, where i will use a lot of linear algebra, like finite fields and matrix multiplication. Since i havent found any suitable libraries for java/kotlin i tried to use sagemath. I found Chaquopa lets you use python code in your android studio project and since you can import sage in a normal python project my hope was, that it would work there too. I ran the usual `sage -python /your/pythonscript.py` and then `from sage.all import *` in the file. However i get this error `com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage'`
is there any way to use sage in chaquopy or do i have to use another program to make a android app with such mathematical functions? thx

Answer (score 0):

Chaquopy does not currently support sagemath, but it does support NumPy and SciPy, which have extensive linear algebra support. You can add them to your app in the `pip` block of your build.gradle file, as shown [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-requirements).